# Compare 2 files line by line

Tags: comparison, diff, text-files

Assume that I have 2 files, like that:

File 1:

```
Verrucomicrobiaceae

Porphyromonadaceae
Clostridium
Verrucomicrobiaceae
Clostridium
Bacteroidaceae
Clostridium
Verrucomicrobiaceae
Verrucomicrobiaceae
Verrucomicrobiaceae
Verrucomicrobiaceae
Clostridium
```

File 2:

```
Verrucomicrobiaceae

Porphyromonadaceae

Verrucomicrobiaceae

Porphyromonadaceae

Verrucomicrobiaceae
Verrucomicrobiaceae
Verrucomicrobiaceae
Verrucomicrobiaceae
```

I would like to count the occurrences of the following:

1. No. of incidences where lines in file 1 and 2 are identical
2. No. of incidences where lines in file 1 and 2 are different
3. No. of incidences where a line in file 1 has a string, while the same line in file 2 has nothing (blank)
4. No. of incidences where a line in file 2 has a string, while the same line in file 1 has nothing (blank)

I tried to use `comm`, `cmp` and `diff`, but they couldn't do that task.
Is there any linux command that can do this?

Comment: A simple `awk` script will do, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is specialized enough that it probably isn't easy to do by standard tools. I'd write a program doing the comparing, like in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open(IN1, "< file1");
open(IN2, "< file2");

$count1 = $count2 = $count3 = $count4 = 0;
while(<IN1>) {
   $line1 = $_;
   $line2 = <IN2>;
   $count1++ if($line1 eq $line2);
   $count2++ if($line1 ne $line2);
   $count3++ if($line1 ne "" && $line2 eq "");
   $count4++ if($line1 eq "" && $line2 ne "");
}
print "$count1 $count2 $count3 $count4\n";
```

No error checking at all, assumes both files are the same length, ...

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the help, the code is working well except that the empty line is matched with "\n" and not "".